# Do 120V pool lights need GFI protection

Tags: electrical

I have a pool at our recently purchased home.  The pool system in about 22 years old and consists of a Hayward / Goldline AquaLogic controller.  The breakers in the controller are marked type QP but I can’t find any markings to indicate they are GFI’s. My logic says that outdoor 120/240 volt circuits require GFI Protection.  The main breaker panel is using a 4 pole 20/30/30/20 ganged breaker.  Could it be a GFI breaker?

Comment: Do these pool lights accept a normal lightbulb, or some other sort of lightbulb?

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't a "test" button on the breakers in question, then it's not a GFCI breaker. Look for a separate panel maybe mounted on the wall by the controller.

Also the pool lights installed in your pool won't be 120V. They'll probably be 12V. There is a stepdown transformer in your control cabinet that lowers the voltage from your line voltage to 12V. Hope this helps.